# Sqlite minutes conversion

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I have a table with a column representing minutes, how can I convert those to hours and minutes?

For example, if I have in a cell "70" to be shown in the select "1h 10min", "60" to be shown "1h", etc.

Comment: Can you show us your effort? What have you tried so far? Any code?

Comment: Consider doing any output formatting in your programming language rather than in database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest returning two derived fields in one query, the first one to get hours (through division), the second one to get minutes (through modulo operator). Try this:

```
select
    minutes / 60 as h,
    minutes % 60 as m

from
    minutes
```

And here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e37a1/2).

**EDIT**

The following shows how the result could be formatted, too. I also updated the fiddle:

```
select
    minutes / 60 as h,
    minutes % 60 as m,
    cast(minutes / 60 as text) || 'h ' || cast(minutes % 60 as text) || 'min' as formatted

from
    minutes
```

Maybe you want to add some conditions to only show hours or minutes greater 0.

Comment: That's not exactly what I expected but thanks anyway

Comment: @Álvaro: Maybe the edit is more adequate. It can be extended easily to meet your needs.